# generate a defined set from an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I'm fetching data from firestore in my android application, I have successfully fetched the data and render it on my views but I would love to remove duplicate data by merging the ones with similar date  together and create a set from it.My Model is provide below.

```java
public Daily(int mDal, int mDeposit, int mWithdrawed, int mReached, String mAuth, String mDate) {
        this.mDal = mDal;
        this.mDeposit = mDeposit;
        this.mWithdrawed = mWithdrawed;
        this.mReached = mReached;
        this.mAuth = mAuth;
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }
```

This is the code use to retrieve from firestore

```java
    db.collection("payments")
                .whereEqualTo("month", month1)
//                .whereEqualTo("year", mYear)
                .whereEqualTo("Paydate", mDay)
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                mProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "payments collected!\n size is " + list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : list) {
                        CustomerPayment acc = snapshot.toObject(CustomerPayment.class);


                            accounts.add(acc);



                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                mProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: post the code which is used to fetch data from firebase

Comment: Do you got a unique identifier? 
Get that one as well from firestorm and that might help with filtering the data. 
So you could just loop through the data and remove the duplicates by ID? where (ID found in set bigger as 1)

Answer (score 0):

So first I want to believe you have included date as an attribute to your data in the firebase database such that the res returns the specific date for each entry. If you haven't make sure to do so.

Use firestore's querying capabilities.:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. The query will help you get all the entries with the same date. There are code examples given on the link and are quite straightforward. Take a look.

```
firestoreDB.collection("payments")
            .whereEqualTo("month", month1)
            .whereEqualTo("Paydate",mDay)               
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
                       for(DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                          Event e = doc.toObject(Event.class);                              
                           eventList.add(e);
                       }
           //do the toast

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

use onComplete instead of onSucess and let the list be an arrayList with its own name such as payments.

Comment: Am Querying for the whole year with the data categorize in months

Comment: Why use a completeListenser?